# Create playlist using iPod Library Access API?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, media-player

Is it possible to create a playlist on iOS using the iPod Library Access API? By playlist I mean one that persists globally and can be accessed in the Music app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way for applications to write any information at all to the iPod library, as least in iOS7.1 and earlier.

Comment: This seems to be the general consensus. I'd love to know if that has changed in iOS 7.

Comment: @doogilasovich Unfortunately not - no changes in this area in iOS 7.0 or 7.1 :( I've updated my answer accordingly.